# Why is text in disabled form elements not rendered in black in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, safari6

I am trying to get the text inside disabled input elements to show up in **black**. This works in most browsers:

```
input[type="text"][disabled],
input[type="text"]:disabled {
  color: #000000;
}
```

In Safari (version 6.0.2), however, the text is slightly brighter. What puzzles me most is that when I select the text in my browser and look up the *element information* on my console it clearly shows:

```
rgba(0,0,0)
```

So in the code it is **black** but nonetheless it is rendered in something *other* than black. How is this possible?

Is this a Safari bug?

Thanks for any help in this matter.

Comment: I don't have Safari here, but perhaps it requires the use of the `:disabled` pseudo-class. See [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/CSS3/Selectors/current/html/full/flat/css3-modsel-24.html).

Comment: Tried that already! Doesn't work either.

Comment: "Other than black" but what exactly ?

Comment: I'm giving a `readonly` attribute together with `disabled` and it works. Try `input:disabled` as well.

Answer (score 16):

Try:

> -webkit-text-fill-color: #000000;

This worked in Safari 7.

Comment: worked great for me! Thanks. By the way I'm using safari 8.0.3 with yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

This is odd indeed. It seems that Safari shows the exact color black as gray in a disabled field, whereas other colors are obeyed. As a workaround, you could set `color: #000001`, but it isn’t quite black of course but has a shade of blue.

As a different approach, consider why a field is set to disabled state, yet should be displayed in normal black color. For example, display it in normal text (and turn it to normal input field when you would now make the disabled field enabled).