# Safari CSS Font Color issue

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I'm having a problem with my font color in safari browser on mac book, iphone and ipad.
The disable element turn into gray and I want it to retain its original
color black. The result in firefox and chrome are okay.

*This is my css code:*

```
input[disabled], textarea[disabled],
select[disabled='disabled']{
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

I also tried using color name but he result is the same.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe you can try to add this to your css:   yourelement:disabled { color: #000000 }

Comment: Seems you're not the only one having [**this issue**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547632/why-is-text-in-disabled-form-elements-not-rendered-in-black-in-safari).

Comment: Does `-webkit-text-fill-color` have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is the only solution I found that works on FF, Chrome, Safari and Safari Mobile. Cheers!

```
input[disabled], textarea[disabled],
select[disabled='disabled']{
   -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
   -webkit-opacity: 1; 
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
   background: white;
}
```

Comment: Curious as to how this works in FF but it helped me out so +1.

Comment: Thanks, webkit seems to git disabled inputs a lower opacity, I couldn't figure out why setting the color to #000 didn't help.

Comment: -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
-webkit-opacity: 1;  //on iphone it is required
Thanks it worked for me

Comment: Nice work! This was a really odd and unforeseen problem that cost me a lot of time. You really helped me out!

Comment: Thanks!  The text-fill-color was the key for me.

Comment: I could see a warning as not to use `webkit-text-fill-property` in production websites in the mdn docs   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color.

Answer (score 2):

You could try set it to anything but solid black such as `#00001` or `#000002` in order to get around the issue as safari tries to override it.

```
input[disabled], textarea[disabled],
select[disabled='disabled']{
    color: #000001 !important;
}
```

Comment: It gives me a darkblue color instead of black in safari browser. @smftre

Comment: @kwan_ah, it would do because it's not #000000 ;)