# Color in HTML table not taken into account

Tags: html, css

I use an HTML table on this URL: https://www.pascaldegut.com/pages/prestation-webdesign, with red crosses and green checks.

It works great on desktop, but using my iPhone (Safari), the crosses and checks are black

[image]

Here is a sample of the code I use

```
<table class="blueTable" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="all" frames="border" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width: 40%;">Services</th>
<th style="width: 20%;">Basique</th>
<th style="width: 20%;">PREMIUM</th>
<th style="width: 20%;">GOLD</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="text">Audit & CR Vidéo</td>
<td class="check" style="color: #006600">✔</td>
<td class="check" style="color: #006600">✔</td>
<td class="check" style="color: #006600">✔</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text">Design Page Accueil</td>
<td class="check" style="color: #006600">✔</td>
<td class="check" style="color: #006600">✔</td>
<td class="check" style="color: #006600">✔</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Moreover, I tried to force CSS with this code, without success

```
  td.cross {
    color: FF0000 !important;
  }

  td.check {
    color: 006600 !important;
  }
```

Any idea here?
It's tricky for me to resolve it since I can't replicate the issue from my editor on desktop

Thank you in advance :)
Pascal

Comment: Your CSS values need the hashtags (`color: #006600 !important`). Safari may be reverting to the default black when it can't find these colours.

Comment: ooops forgot the hashtags indeed, but this didn't resolve the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to do with the use of the unicode characters `✖` and `✔`. I was able to inspect element on my iPhone and it seems to be caused by the iPhone Safari pre-defining the style and colour for those characters used. By simply changing them to a font, e.g [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/), you will be able to achieve what you want.

Resources: [Cross](https://fontawesome.com/icons/times?style=solid) - [Tick](https://fontawesome.com/icons/check?style=solid)

**The following are screenshots of my testing:**
[image: Inspect Element: using an <code>x</code> rather than what you've used previously]

[image: Screenshot of the result of the inspect element.]

Comment: should I write <td class="check" style="color: #006600;     font-family: FontAwesome;">✔</td> or something close?
Cause it didn't work :(

Comment: So you need to include the FontAwesome stylesheets into your `<head>` section of your website. You then want to add the following line of code `<i class="fa fa-check"><i>` in place of your current `✔`. Do the same for the cross; however, the class for the cross is `fa fa-times`.

Comment: @Pascal if this fixed your issue, please select this as the working answer.

Answer (score 0):

**I think Safari does not find colors that take this formula : #006600**

**Change it to the following format :** `style="color: rgb(0,102,0)"`

```html
<table class="blueTable" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" rules="all" frames="border" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width: 40%;">Services</th>
<th style="width: 20%;">Basique</th>
<th style="width: 20%;">PREMIUM</th>
<th style="width: 20%;">GOLD</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="text">Audit & CR Vidéo</td>
<td class="check" style="color: rgb(0,102,0)">✔</td>
<td class="check" style="color: rgb(0,102,0)">✔</td>
<td class="check" style="color: rgb(0,102,0)">✔</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text">Design Page Accueil</td>
<td class="check" style="color: rgb(0,102,0)">✔</td>
<td class="check" style="color: rgb(0,102,0)">✔</td>
<td class="check" style="color: rgb(0,102,0)">✔</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your browser version?

Comment: on my iPhone, no idea where to check that at all, but it is update to the latest version I believe

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400182/safari-css-font-color-issue