# Text color is not working on safari iphone

Tags: css, input, mobile-safari

https://wordpress-518403-1889368.cloudwaysapps.com/register-with-us/
on this website, the color property is not working on iPhone on safari for input and select.

```
form#wpforms-form-2408 input,
form#wpforms-form-2408 select{
    color: pink!important;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 78px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: red;
    line-height: unset!important;
    position: relative!important;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
-webkit-text-fill-color: red;
-webkit-text-fill-color: #000000;
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(100, 200, 0);
}
```

I have tried this CSS but still, nothing changes. If you please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this.

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(100, 200, 0, 1); 
-webkit-opacity: 1;
```

As described here: [Safari CSS Font Color issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400182/safari-css-font-color-issue)

Comment: It is working for some input fields but for all. And how about the select fields?

Comment: Read the linked issue. They are discussing select fields as well.

Comment: I removed the code conflict and it is working now. Thanks