# Font color discrepancy between desktop Safari/Chrome and mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I'm testing cross compatibility between Safari and Chrome on both desktop and mobile. I've set something relatively simple for font color.

```
/* JS inline style...something along the lines of this */
const style = {
    color: 'black',
    WebkitTextFillColor: 'black',
}

<input style={style} value={1}/>
```

The text shows up black for desktop Chrome and Safari. It shows up as gray on mobile Chrome and Safari though. What's up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came accross something similar and this is what worked for me:

```
input{
   -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
   -webkit-opacity: 1; 
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
   background: white;
}
```

I think it has something to do with `WebkitTextFillColor`.

See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547632/why-is-text-in-disabled-form-elements-not-rendered-in-black-in-safari), too.